# Vectorize Loop with nested lists in Python

Tags: python, lambda, vectorization

Looking for some help vectorizing a loop in python:

```
for a in range(len(listOne)):
         listTwo.append(listThree[listFour[a]])
```

I want to test potential performance gains not having to call append via a loop. If not vectorization, perhaps a lambda expression might suffice?  Any thoughts or assistance would be immensely helpful!  Thank you for the time!

Comment: Does this add to a non-empty `listTwo`, or was `listTwo` initialized as empty just prior to this?

Comment: listTwo is initialized as empty prior to the loop.

Comment: I think people probably need more context, like what the content of these lists actually is. I'm also not sure what you mean by vectorization in this context, if you're using `numpy` then vectorized operations are generally faster but in standard Python there's not necessarily a huge difference between for loops and list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with your loop, but you could change it to a comprehension if you want to avoid the `append()`:

```
listTwo = [listThree[listFour[a]] for a in range(len(listOne))]
```